# Having multiple text column vs single text column / medium text column

Tags: mysql, performance

Having multiple text column in a table vs single text column / medium text column? Which should scale better?

Example :

```
Table t :

Col1 : {a:1} // .. could me larger than varchar 35565
Col2 : {b:1} // .. could me larger than varchar 35565
Col3 : {c:1} // .. could me larger than varchar 35565
```

vs

```
Col : {a:1, b:1, c: 1} // might be medium text to handle the extra size.
```

Answer (score 0):

In se, there won't be a huge difference.

What can make a difference:

- your application logic. If you often have to select just/ search on /change A, B or C, it's better having them in separate columns.
- indexes

Comment: In case i need all the columns on each reads : The number of file lookups mysql would do on disk? Shouldnt it reduce with lesser text columns? Just a thought.

Comment: If you always need them all: yes, one field could be saved more compact, and read out faster. Unless you use table fragmentation, in which three fields can be faster again ;) It really depends on so many factors. Generally: follow the functional design, see what the data represents. Is it together? Store it together.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely **NOT** do that. Read about [the first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), it explains why this is a horrible idea. Each particular column must hold atomic values.

At first, it may seem easier to merge those columns together, but in time you'll come to regret it. Trust me, I've been there. By merging the columns, the risk of bugs grows exponentially. You'll also probably end up with a lot of junk data in your database.

Another issue is this: How do you know where one "column" (notice the quotes) ends and another begins ? Will you use a special character ? What happens when you want that special character to appear within that text ?

It's too much of a headache, it's not worth it. Do it the right way !